# How can I find an illustrator who can produce game art in a particular style?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration

I have searched a number of sites like Behance, Dribbble for an illustrator with flat vector-like art style similar to Two Dots and Jellies. I've not made any progress. How can I find an illustrator who has a similar style? I'm actually looking for someone that does a style similar to these, but suggestions on how to find illustrators of any particular style would be helpful.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how you've searched, but there's pleeenty of designers that do that style in dribbble: https://dribbble.com/search?q=flat%2C+illustration

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I edited it to include the style you're after but also be applicable to anyone seeking a particular style of illustrator.

Comment: There are places like http://www.theispot.com/ which specialize in connecting illustrators with clients.

Comment: I would think there are many Illustrators that could easily adapt to this style. Most creative people aren't limited to one style. I'm pretty sure I could nail this style myself. Like others have said look for an artist on Dribble or Behance and show them some examples of what you want. Pay them to produce one screen for you to see if it satisfies you once you think you have found the artist you want to use.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like flat design. There are a lot of illustrators that upload how-to videos for flat design on Youtube.